# Reference full name list in xdata field

Tags: biblatex, biber

When using the xdata type in biblatex/biber I can reference the full entry, and I can reference individual authors from a name list by index. But is there also a way to reference the full author list?

E.g. in the following example I would want to get both authors also in citation 2:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{xdata-test.bib}
@XData{somenames,
author  ={Maria White and Julia Green},
location={Paris and London}
}

@book{somebook:a,
xdata  = {somenames},
title  = {All xdata}
}

@book{somebook:b,
author = {xdata=somenames-author},
title =  {Author=somenames-author}
}

@book{somebook:c,
author = {xdata=somenames-author-1 and xdata=somenames-author-2},
title  = {Author=somenames-author-1 and -2}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{xdata-test.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{somebook:a,somebook:b,somebook:c}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You'd think that `author = {xdata=somenames-author},` should do it given how `author = {xdata=somenames-author-1 and xdata=somenames-author-2},` works. So I'm inclined to say this is something to take to the Biber bugtracker as feature request: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues

Comment: For posterity: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/387